# Singular Value Decomposition Solving the U & V

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I am following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EokL7E6o1AE&t=812s) on YouTube. I have a question on 41 minute mark.

When solving for $V$, $A^t A V = V \Sigma^2$, have been rearrange to

$$Ax = \lambda x$$

Why can $V \Sigma ^2$ become $\Sigma ^ 2 V$? I thought matrix multiplication is non-commutative.

[image]

Comment: The second equality in the picture says that each column of matrix
$V$ is an eigenvector for matrix $A^TA$. Of course, in the general
case $V\Sigma^2\neq\Sigma^2V$. (Here $\Sigma^2$ seems to be a
notation for $\Sigma\Sigma^*$).